# Multiple AJAX Requests - Troublesome?

Tags: javascript, ajax, streaming

Right now I'm using AJAX to pull in a list of active streams (TwitchTV) and it's viewers and I'm requesting this every second. At time the list of streams to check can get quite lengthy so I plan on splitting the ajax requests into 2 or 3 parts:

1) Get Number of Viewers for Current Stream (Check every 1 Second)

2) Split Stream in Half and Check 1st Half of List for Active Streamers (Check every 5 Seconds)

3) Check 2nd Half of List for Active Streamers (Check every 5 Seconds)

so I would have 3 requests running simultaneously but I'm worried about what the load time will come down to. Since it is constantly pulling in data would it make the page slower? Would the user likely notice? Is it better to keep 1 ajax request for big amounts of data or is it better to use multiple ajax requests for smaller pieces of data? Is ajax really the best thing to pull in constantly changing live data?

Comment: That would put loads of strains on the server that you're sending requests to - is it vital the info updates every couple of seconds? If not, consider caching and updating every minute. Also research websockets (HTML5) if you want the client/server connection to be continuous.

Comment: well technically it's not going to my server - I'm using Twitch TV API - so it pings a url of their to get channel information. Though I do process it on my server if that's what you mean. Well I update it every second to show the number of active viewers and I do not want Active Channels to show up in my list for a few minutes if they're really not active. I have sorta looked into http://socket.io but haven't really used it. Will do though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your various questions is probably "It depends":

1. The ajax requests by themselves shouldn't make anything slower.  These are asynchronous requests, so they will only actually cause the user's browser any significant (and probably still not noticeable) load when the request completes.
2. One thing that could potentially slow your app down (or cause the user to notice in an unpleasant way) is the DOM manipulation when the request completes.  Changing your current number of streaming users in-place probably won't hurt, but depending on the number of streams/how you are displaying them in a list, redrawing this could potentially be very expensive/cause lag on things like redraw.
3. An alternative to using Ajax (depending on what browsers you wish to support) is to use websockets.  This way you can keep a connection open and the server can tell the application when the data needs to change, instead of the need to poll for it.
4. Why do you need to break your list up into a first half and a second half?
5. One way to cut down on the amount of data you're sending back and forth might be to send some sort of signal indicating the last bit of data you received.  For example, when your timeline on twitter.com updates every few seconds, the ajax request sends along the id of the most recent tweet it received, so that the server knows not to waste time sending any data older than that.  Depending on your use case this might be effective.

Comment: First off thanks for the response. (3)I've heard of web sockets but didn't think it was beneficial so I'd really have to do some research. (2)I am redrawing the whole list every time - sorta. Really I'm just changing an image from red to green if it's active and moving it to the top of the UL. (4)I thought about breaking it up incase the list was too big - instead of doing 1 big request I thought it might be more beneficial but really I  don't know it was just a thought. (5) Not sure what you mean but I am using TwitchTV API so I might not have premissions / capability to do so.

Comment: If you are calling their API directly from your ajax requests, using websockets probably isn't an option, and neither is my point 5.  The best way to accomplish either of these would have a worker process of your own consuming the twitch api and provide a middle layer that gave clients the functionality they need. This would also help alleviate possible rate limiting issues.

Disclaimer: I have never worked with this API so I'm not sure what you are actually trying to do/what its limitations may be.

Comment: Web Sockets might work (from what I've read so far) since really you're just pinging a url ([example](http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/list.json?channel=day9tv)) via PHP and getting a json response. Not sure what you mean by worker process though.

Comment: Meant that you could have a process running on your server that regularly pulls down the info you need and stores it locally.  Then you could expose your own api to the users, allowing it to behave in whatever way you need it to.  Again, this may be overly complicating it depending on your use case.